# Android device owner app access other apps files

Tags: android, android-permissions, kiosk, device-owner

I am working on a KIOSK device, and I have two apps on the device. One is the device owner, the other isn't.

I am trying to access the /data/data/not_device_owner_app/files/.. and load files from the device owner application.

I am getting a permission denied exception when doing so.

Question is, how can I grant this permission to my device owner app to able to access my other app's files directory?

Comment: You can't access another app's internal directories like that directly. Look into [FileProviders](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). They will allow you to securely share files to different apps on the device.

Comment: @kabumere Thanks I'll look into that. I just found it interesting that I could do it on one device (android 6) and couldn't on another (android 7).

Comment: Android apps are completely sandboxed, so there shouldn't have been anyway for App1 to have accessed App2's internal app directories, regardless of Android version. Was the Android 6 device rooted?

Comment: @kabumere yes it was, but I thought having the device-owner permission is the same as having the device rooted.

Comment: I have not developed an app that uses the (now deprecated) Device Admin APIs. But from my research, it is not comparable to rooting your device. This [Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127513) and its Answers might help you a bit. But to wrap back around - you were able to access other app's private internal data on the Android 6 device because it was rooted. On a normal device where security has not been circumvented, Android apps must use APIs like the FileProvider that I pointed you to before in order to seucrely share files across apps.

Comment: I presume that you already have and granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the device admin. If that doesn't work the suggestion from kabumere stands. If you have control of the code of the other application you should implement a file provider or move the storage of that app to an accessible location (I recommend the former).